# Crumpled paper UIView animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, animation

Do you know of any iOS library that takes a UIView and crumple it as an animation?

Just to give an illustration of what crumple means in this context:

[image]

[image: screenshot]

(screenshots taken from a CSS crumple effect)

Most likely does not exist, but was wondering...

Comment: That looks like a background, not an animation.  If it is an animation, I'd expect it's an animated background, not a transition.

Comment: Crumple a piece of paper, make a picture of it and use it as background.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. I would like an animation that takes a UIView and crumple it. So it is a computed animation, not a static image. The image was just to show the type of final effect desired.

Comment: I edited the post to be more precise about what I am trying to achieve. Please vote for re-opening - thanks!

Comment: @ott-- If it was just a background the lettering would not be distorted.

Comment: I was talking yesterday to my son who designs graphics processors for Intel.  He stated that this sort of thing requires 3D-type processing with a "texture processor", the same sort of stuff that would be needed to map an image to a sphere, etc.

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks. Please vote to reopen this question.

Comment: @Resh32 Have you found any such library?